# Is Hibernate safer for Web Applications?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, hibernate, servlets

I have a doubt whether `Hibernate` is safe for web applications (JSP, Servlet, Hibernate, MySQL) where it will gain thousands of access "at once" by "different users".

The reason for my worry is something like below.

Imagine I have a web application for a school students. They have their own profile and will maintain their own student courses, marks and so on. Now, definitely more than  1 user will be online all the time, with their own profiles. That means if user `A` made an edit to his maths marks, it will be done in user `A`s profile. It will never be replaced in all user `A`, `B` and 'C`s profiles who were online at the same time.

`Servlets` are multi threaded to provide the above support. It works pretty well as expected with pure JDBC. How is it with  `Hibernate` ?

I have also uploaded my `HibernateUtil` for your reference. In my case I am calling it as `SessionFactoryBuilder`

```
public class SessionFactoryBuilder
{
    private static SessionFactoryBuilder instance;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private SessionFactoryBuilder()
    {
        buildConfig();
        System.out.println("hehehehe");
    }

    private static void buildConfig()
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    }

    public static SessionFactoryBuilder getInstance()
    {
         if(instance == null)
         {
            instance = new SessionFactoryBuilder();

         }
      return instance;
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes hibernate is safe to use. It just provides you with ORM relation ...rest all is pretty same as in JDBC

Comment: @Naruto: Even in my given example where multiple users will be online at the same time and no data will be overlapped ?

Comment: @Drew: errr.... I am confused??

Comment: It was an orm joke

Comment: @Drew: ok so it is safe?

Comment: I do not see why it would not be safe , Hibernate provides you with a way to model your data directly from the java model, the rest will be done by the JDBC driver which will be the same either you used Hibernate or not

Comment: OK Guys now my `SessionFactoryBuilder" is singleton. That's how we do with JDBC too. Will this singleton be an issue? I hope not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** In Hibernate there exists a **Single SessionFactory object** per application.
Internal state of SessionFactory is **immutable**, **so it’s thread safe**.   Multiple threads can access it simultaneously to get Session instances.

Below code depicts a standard way to get the SessionFactory instance via a Utility class.

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

/**
 * Hibernate Utility class with a method to get Session Factory object.
 */
public class HibernateUtil {
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;//Once created, its properties cannot be changed

static {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) config file.

        sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    } catch (Throwable ex) {

        // Log the exception.
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

    return sessionFactory;

}
}
```

**2)** Hibernate **Session** is the interface between java application layer and hibernate. This is the core interface used to perform database operations. 
The lifecycle of a Session is bounded by the beginning and end of a logical transaction.

**Hibernate Session object is not thread safe**, every thread should get it’s own session instance and close it after it’s work is finished.

It is not intended/meant that implementors be threadsafe. Instead each thread/transaction should obtain its own instance from a SessionFactory.

```
A typical transaction should use the following idiom:

 Session sess = factory.openSession();
 Transaction tx;
 try {
     tx = sess.beginTransaction();
     //do some work
     ...
     tx.commit();
     }
 catch (Exception e) {
    if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
    throw e;
 }
 finally {
      sess.close();
 }
```

If the Session throws an exception, the transaction must be rolled back and the session discarded. **The internal state of the Session might not be consistent with the database after the exception occurs.**

**2.1)** Below listed are two ways widely used to get the Hibernate Session Object.

1. **openSession**       //Use this for **Multi-threaded** environment
2. **getCurrentSession** //Use this for **single threaded** environment

Hibernate SessionFactory **getCurrentSession() method returns the session bound to the context.** But for this to work, we need to configure it in hibernate configuration file. Since this session object belongs to the hibernate context, we don’t need to close it. Once the SessionFactory is closed, this session object gets closed.

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Hibernate SessionFactory **openSession()** method always opens a new session. We should **close** this session object once we are done with all the database operations.
**We should open a new session for each request in multi-threaded environment.**

---

**2.2) There is one more way to create the Hibernate Session object using openStatelessSession() that gives you a hibernate Stateless Session.**

It is a  command-oriented API for performing bulk operations against a database.
A stateless session does not implement a first-level cache nor interact with any second-level cache, nor does it implement transactional write-behind or automatic dirty checking, nor do operations cascade to associated instances. Collections are ignored by a stateless session. Operations performed via a stateless session bypass Hibernate's event model and interceptors. Stateless sessions are vulnerable to data aliasing effects, due to the lack of a first-level cache.

**For certain kinds of transactions, a stateless session may perform slightly faster than a stateful session.(For example: Batch processing/Bulk update)**

```
StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

ScrollableResults customers = session.getNamedQuery("GetCustomers")
.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
while ( customers.next() ) {
Customer customer = (Customer) customers.get(0);
customer.updateStuff(...);
session.update(customer);
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

In this code example, the Customer instances returned by the query are immediately detached. They are never associated with any persistence context.

The insert(), update() and delete() operations defined by the StatelessSession interface are considered to be direct database row-level operations. They result in the immediate execution of a SQL INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE respectively.

**The Stateless Session is not thread-safe**, possible exception occurs while using stateless session is "org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible non-threadsafe access to the session"

---

**3)** Your Student records project is a multi-threaded application, so you need to be careful while using hibernate. Try to use best programming practices by opening a new session, make usage of transactions, commit and rollback and closing the session whenever needed.

I personally have used hibernate in our project where we have millions of users accessing the database via hibernate as back-end API. We never faced such issues in our multi-threaded environment, Since we used the best programming practices of hibernate. Even though any exception occurs with the DB, the entire transaction is rolled back.

Hence, the  ACID properties (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability) of database transactions can be achieved at higher success rate as compared with JDBC.

Comment: OK Thank you for the detailed answer. So in short, Hibernate is safe for web applications where thousands of users access at once. Isn't it? (Yes, the opening/closing session and transaction rollback need to happen to achieve this.). In your answer you mentioned **transactions must be rolled back if any error** , now is this applicable to `select statements ` as well? In JDBC we don't do that because there is nothing to roll back in `select`?

Comment: yes, its safe for web applications. In hibernate, there is no need to rollback for SELECT because, the select query will never alter the state of database.

Comment: Thanks. So what should I use? `getCurrentSession()` or `openSession()` ? I am using `openSession()`

Comment: You should use openSession() as your application is in multi-threaded environment. getCurrentSession should be used for single-threaded apps, here only one session will be available and it's lifecycle is managed by the hibernate context, so no need to close it.

Comment: `multi-threaded environment` - You mean servlets isnt it? As far as I know they are multi threaded by default

Comment: remember, you should use 'static final' non-access modifiers for SessionFactory object. Once, created its value should not able to altered programmatically, as in your code final is missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124202/discussion-between-rohit-gaikwad-and-peakgen).

Comment: Anyway regarding `final`, even if final is used then we can't initialize the object in a different method of the same class, instead have to initialize right next to final.

Comment: As there is a single instance of SessionFactory object in a web app, it's initialization should be done only once(no need to initialize the object in a different method of the same class). Using static block for initialization is just a good practice to write less code.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer and detailed long communication. Accepted as the answer.

Comment: Hi, can you please check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786509/hibernate-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-session-through-reference-chain