# Hibernate: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain....)

Tags: java, hibernate, rest

Note: Before anyone complain about this is a duplicate, make sure to go through the content without judging by title. Also make sure to read your reference question and the answer carefully to see whether it is duplicate. As of my experience now, the issue in this question can happen under different environments. For an example, the answer for someone using the below code in `jsp` will be different, for someone using `Spring` will be different and for someone whose DB is small and `eager` load is fine will be different. And no, my situation is not any of them.

---

I am writing a `REST` api using `Hibernate`and `Jersey`. Please have a look at the below code.

**VerificationCodeJSONService.java** - The JSON Service class

```
@Path("/verificaion_code")
public class VerificationCodeJSONService {

    @GET
    @Path("/getAllVerificationCodes")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<VerificaionCode> getAllVerificationCodes() {

        VerificationCodeService verificationCodeService=new VerificationCodeService();
        List<VerificaionCode> list = verificationCodeService.getAllVerificationCodes();
        return list;
    }
}
```

**VerificationCodeService.java** - The Service Layer

```
public class VerificationCodeService {    

    private static VerificationCodeDAOInterface verificationCodeDAOInterface;

    public VerificationCodeService() {
        verificationCodeDAOInterface = new VerificationCodeDAOImpl();
    }

    public List<VerificaionCode> getAllVerificationCodes() {
        Session session = verificationCodeDAOInterface.openCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;

        List<VerificaionCode> verificaionCodes = new ArrayList<VerificaionCode>();

        try {
            transaction = verificationCodeDAOInterface.openTransaction(session);
            verificaionCodes = verificationCodeDAOInterface.getAllVerificationCodes(session);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return verificaionCodes;

    }
}
```

**VerificationCodeDAOImpl.java** - The database layer

```
public class VerificationCodeDAOImpl implements VerificationCodeDAOInterface{

    private static final SessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder = SessionFactoryBuilder.getInstance();

    @Override
    public List<VerificaionCode> getAllVerificationCodes(Session session) {
        List<VerificaionCode> verificaionCodes=(List<VerificaionCode>)session.createQuery("from VerificaionCode").list();
        return verificaionCodes;
    }
}
```

**VerificationCode.java** - The DAO layer

```
public class VerificaionCode implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idverificaionCode;
    private Patient patient;
    private String code;
    private Date dateCreated;
    private Date lastUpdated;

    public VerificaionCode() {
    }

    public VerificaionCode(Patient patient, String code, Date lastUpdated) {
        this.patient = patient;
        this.code = code;
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

    public VerificaionCode(Patient patient, String code, Date dateCreated, Date lastUpdated) {
        this.patient = patient;
        this.code = code;
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

    public Integer getIdverificaionCode() {
        return this.idverificaionCode;
    }

    public void setIdverificaionCode(Integer idverificaionCode) {
        this.idverificaionCode = idverificaionCode;
    }

    public Patient getPatient() {
        return this.patient;
    }

    public void setPatient(Patient patient) {
        this.patient = patient;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return this.dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdated() {
        return this.lastUpdated;
    }

    public void setLastUpdated(Date lastUpdated) {
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

}
```

**Patient.java** - The DAO layer

```
public class Patient  implements java.io.Serializable {

     private Integer idpatient;
     private DiabetesType diabetesType;
     private Language language;
     private String customId;
     private String diabetesOther;
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     private String email;
     private Date dob;
     private String parentEmail;
     private String gender;
     private Date diagnosedDate;
     private Double height;
     private Double weight;
     private String heightUnit;
     private String weightUnit;
     private String theme;
     private String userName;
     private String password;
     private Date dateCreated;
     private Date lastUpdated;

    public Patient() {
    }


    public Patient(DiabetesType diabetesType, Language language, String customId, String firstName, String email, Date dob, String gender, String theme, String userName, String password, Date lastUpdated) {
        this.diabetesType = diabetesType;
        this.language = language;
        this.customId = customId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.email = email;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.theme = theme;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

    public Integer getIdpatient() {
        return this.idpatient;
    }

    public void setIdpatient(Integer idpatient) {
        this.idpatient = idpatient;
    }
    public DiabetesType getDiabetesType() {
        return this.diabetesType;
    }

    public void setDiabetesType(DiabetesType diabetesType) {
        this.diabetesType = diabetesType;
    }
    public Language getLanguage() {
        return this.language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(Language language) {
        this.language = language;
    }
    public String getCustomId() {
        return this.customId;
    }

    public void setCustomId(String customId) {
        this.customId = customId;
    }
    public String getDiabetesOther() {
        return this.diabetesOther;
    }

    public void setDiabetesOther(String diabetesOther) {
        this.diabetesOther = diabetesOther;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Date getDob() {
        return this.dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    public String getParentEmail() {
        return this.parentEmail;
    }

    public void setParentEmail(String parentEmail) {
        this.parentEmail = parentEmail;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return this.gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public Date getDiagnosedDate() {
        return this.diagnosedDate;
    }

    public void setDiagnosedDate(Date diagnosedDate) {
        this.diagnosedDate = diagnosedDate;
    }
    public Double getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }

    public void setHeight(Double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
    public Double getWeight() {
        return this.weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(Double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    public String getHeightUnit() {
        return this.heightUnit;
    }

    public void setHeightUnit(String heightUnit) {
        this.heightUnit = heightUnit;
    }
    public String getWeightUnit() {
        return this.weightUnit;
    }

    public void setWeightUnit(String weightUnit) {
        this.weightUnit = weightUnit;
    }
    public String getTheme() {
        return this.theme;
    }

    public void setTheme(String theme) {
        this.theme = theme;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return this.dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }
    public Date getLastUpdated() {
        return this.lastUpdated;
    }

    public void setLastUpdated(Date lastUpdated) {
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }
}
```

Below are my `Hibernate` mapping files for the above POJOs

**VerificaionCode.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 23, 2016 3:21:00 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="beans.VerificaionCode" table="verificaion_code" catalog="myglukose" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="idverificaionCode" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="idverificaion_code" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="patient" class="beans.Patient" fetch="select">
            <column name="patient_idpatient" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="code" type="string">
            <column name="code" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateCreated" type="timestamp">
            <column name="date_created" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastUpdated" type="timestamp">
            <column name="last_updated" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Patient.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Sep 23, 2016 3:21:00 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="beans.Patient" table="patient" catalog="myglukose" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="idpatient" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="idpatient" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="diabetesType" class="beans.DiabetesType" fetch="select">
            <column name="diabetes_type_iddiabetes_type" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="language" class="beans.Language" fetch="select">
            <column name="language_idlanguage" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="customId" type="string">
            <column name="custom_id" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="diabetesOther" type="string">
            <column name="diabetes_other" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="firstName" type="string">
            <column name="first_name" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastName" type="string">
            <column name="last_name" length="100" />
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="string">
            <column name="email" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="dob" type="date">
            <column name="dob" length="10" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="parentEmail" type="string">
            <column name="parent_email" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="gender" type="string">
            <column name="gender" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="diagnosedDate" type="date">
            <column name="diagnosed_date" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="height" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="height" precision="22" scale="0" />
        </property>
        <property name="weight" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="weight" precision="22" scale="0" />
        </property>
        <property name="heightUnit" type="string">
            <column name="height_unit" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="weightUnit" type="string">
            <column name="weight_unit" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="theme" type="string">
            <column name="theme" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="userName" type="string">
            <column name="user_name" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="password" type="string">
            <column name="password" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateCreated" type="timestamp">
            <column name="date_created" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastUpdated" type="timestamp">
            <column name="last_updated" length="19" not-null="true">
                <comment>Stores the basic information of the patient</comment>
            </column>
        </property>        
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

However when I run this code via `http://localhost:8080/example_rest/rest/verificaion_code/getAllVerificationCodes` I am getting the below error.

```
could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->beans.VerificaionCode["patient"]->beans.Patient_$$_jvst40f_7["diabetesType"])
```

As you can see `diabetesType` is an `Object` (Foreign Key) in the patient's table and has nothing to do with `VerificationCode`. How can I fix this up?

Please note that this is a `REST` API. So I can't load these in a JSP like in a web app.

---

**Update**

As @Kayaman recommended, I made the updates by making `null`. Please check the below code. I noticed that `verificaionCodes.get(i).getPatient().set...(null)` makes the same error as above, so I tried below which started working fine.

**VerificationCodeService.java**

```
public List<VerificaionCode> getAllVerificationCodes() {
        Session session = verificationCodeDAOInterface.openCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;

        List<VerificaionCode> verificaionCodes = new ArrayList<VerificaionCode>();

        try {
            transaction = verificationCodeDAOInterface.openTransaction(session);
            verificaionCodes = verificationCodeDAOInterface.getAllVerificationCodes(session);

            transaction.commit();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();

            for(int i=0;i<verificaionCodes.size();i++)
            {
                Patient p = new Patient();

System.out.println(verificaionCodes.get(i).getPatient().getIdpatient());
                Integer idpatient = verificaionCodes.get(i).getPatient().getIdpatient();
                p.setIdpatient(idpatient);
                verificaionCodes.get(i).setPatient(p);
            }
        }

        return verificaionCodes;

    }
```

Comment: @Kayaman: Maybe, do you know how to address this in given situation ?

Comment: Maybe. But since you don't bother answering me honestly, why should I help you?

Comment: @Kayaman: I did not request you to come and help. It is your wish to help or not. If you do not want to help, then it is fine. Also, you asked whether I know about the underlying problem or question closing??

Comment: I asked whether you know what the whole proxy init error means. It's not exactly a rare issue, but people still don't always understand it. It's like the `NullPointerException` of Hibernate.

Comment: @Kayaman: Oh, hmm, OK.. That's weird. Definitely nothing is null in code (according to my understand, maybe I am wrong). Whats your advice on this please? Non of the solutions in the internet seems to address this issue, wondering anyone used Hibernate to do something away from Web View

Comment: No, I meant that it's as common as a `NPE`, and it only has a single reason. You need to initialize the proxies while the session is open. You claim that you can't perform eager fetch, why is that? Also this is not related to JSPs or web or anything else like that. This is a pure basic Hibernate thing. Why aren't you performing an eager fetch in your query?

Comment: @Kayaman: 1. My `Patient` is using lot of `foreign keys`. Just to load `Verification Code` who has the foreign key of `Patient`, I do not want to laod everything where `Patient` has as `foreign keys`. There are around 7 tables in real code, whose `foreign keys` are loaded in `Patient` table. Definitly I don't want `diabetes` info when calling `getAllVerificationCodes` because `VerificationCode` table don't even has it's foreign key.

Comment: @Kayaman: 2. It was mentioned as a bad practice by a highly reputed programmer in SO because it loads every single thing. Here it will load `diabetes` info which has no relationship with `VerificationCodes`

Comment: @Kayaman: Posting my table structures might help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124624/discussion-between-kayaman-and-peakgen).

Comment: Looks like you are using getCurrentSession() in openCurrentSession method of VerificationCodeDAOInterface, this leads to usage of a single session in your app. As @Kayaman said it's been closed, this is because the hibernate context handles this session. As you may know that where to use which session have been discussed in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694677/is-hibernate-safer-for-web-applications. Also, I can't see implementation  of openCurrentSession method in VerificationCodeDAOImpl  class.

Comment: @Kayaman: Give me 10 mins pls.. I will be back

Comment: @Rohit Gaikwad I agree with you and I feel weird too. If here is only one session made by sessionFactory, I guess his API can' t be called twice. I also would like to see the implemention of that method. Anyway, I think the problem is just like Kayaman said, the session in proxy has been closed. Because you mark "fetch=select" to patient, the lazy load will be triggered when the JSON Data Transfer happens. It'll go to fetch the patient but the session is closed.

Comment: Here's the source code of LazyInitializer:http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.0.CR3/org/hibernate/proxy/LazyInitializer.java#LazyInitializer.  You can find the implmentation in Hierarchy tab. Currently, I've two solutions for you. One, using fetch=eager if you really want Patient data in your JSON. Two, you may use '@JsonIgnore', I don't know which lib do you use. You may find the same annotation to exclude the unused property in JSON serialize.

Comment: @Kayaman: I have another thing to settle up, by setting things to null, this is what I am gonna do. In `VerificationCodeDAOImpl` after loading the data I am going to create a `for loop` and set everything I do not need in `POJO` TO NULL. Is this is it??

Comment: @Kayaman: Reading the chat, It says to do this null work after closing the `Session`, so I guess it is after closing `Session` on `finally` block of `VerificationCodeService `? I will try now

Comment: @PeakGen Well it doesn't need to be in a finally block. Just after you've retrieved the data and before it gets serialized to JSON.

Comment: @Kayaman: Please check the update. I couldn't do it as `verificaionCodes.get(i).getPatient().set...(null)` because the same exception was coming back, therefor I made a new object and passed required data into it. Please check the code in update and confirm that is what you were advising please?