# why do Iget closed session outside of spring Context

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session

I'm trying to configure spring with hibernate, and I noticed one thing I can not get: when I tryied to get Session object from Container.
 `Bean.getBean(GenericDao.class).getCurrentSession();` I can only get closed session.
If I will do same with `openSession()` method - I would receive valid session.
  So the question is next: why? I ve been researching in google, but did not find answer. Do anybody knows?

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@Transactional ( propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = { Throwable.class } )
public abstract class GenericDao {

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public Session openSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(final Serializable object) {
        getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(object);
    }

    public void delete(final Serializable object) {
        getCurrentSession().delete(object);
    }

    public void save(final Serializable object) {
        getCurrentSession().save(object);
    }

    public void update(final Serializable object) {
        getCurrentSession().update(object);
    }

    public void merge(final Serializable object) {
        getCurrentSession().merge(object);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings ( "unchecked" )
    public <T> List<T> list(final Class<T> clazz) {
        return getCurrentSession().createCriteria(clazz).list();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings ( "unchecked" )
    public <T> T get(final Class<T> clazz, final Serializable id) {
        return (T) getCurrentSession().get(clazz, id);
    }

}

@Repository
@Primary
class GenericDaoImpl extends GenericDao {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** This is because, using `getCurrentSession()` **method returns the session bound to the context**. But for this to work, we need to configure it in hibernate configuration file as below.

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

`thread` context means current thread. The default value is `jta` context means an already existing jta transaction.
Since this session object (fetched using `getCurrentSession()`) belongs to the hibernate context, we don’t need to close it. Once the SessionFactory is closed, this session object gets closed.

The `getCurrentSession()` should be used for single threaded environment.

**2)** `openSession()` method always opens a new session. We should close this session object once we are done with all the database operations.
**We should open a new session for each request in multi-threaded environment.**

For more details related to thread safety and Hibernate Session & their usage, please see [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694677/is-hibernate-safer-for-web-applications/39697240#39697240)

Comment: Are you trying to that is hibernate context was born inside spring one, that means that its impossible to `session` obtained from `getCurrenSession()` method be alive outside of spring context? Did I understand you properly?

Comment: In your case the hibernate context is managed by Spring, And it is possible to obtain the session from `getCurrenSession()` method but you need to configure the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` property value properly, because the default value is "JTA" i.e, an already existing jta transaction that may close your session before fetching it(session).

Comment: Well, situation became more clearly... Thank for your reply, I will check it

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate uses a the notion of current context class to determine the scope of the Session to use with getCurrentSession(). In pure Hibernate this can be thread whereby the Session is bound to the thread , jta where the session is bound to a JTA UserTransaction

When used with Spring you dont need to specify the hibernate.current_session_context_class property as Spring uses its own called SpringSessionContext. This binds the session to the ongoing transaction using whatever PlatformTransactionManager you are using

To use SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() make sure your call is inside a @Transactional method otherwise it wont work and you have to open the session manually using openSession()

Comment: I am sorry, could you be more clear, or can you give me a link to resource where you have found this info. Intuitively I understand that this is answer on my question, but i did not get main point of first two paragraphs

Answer (score 1):

@Transactional takes responsibility for opening and closing sessionFactory, you can use getCurrentSession without openSession as: 
    `@SuppressWarnings ( "unchecked" )
 public <T> List<T> list(final Class<T> clazz) {
    return getCurrentSession().createCriteria(clazz).list();
}`

if you configured transaction with @Annotation or in .xml file as here: 
    `<bean id="sessionFactory" class="..."`
`</bean>`
    `<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="txManager" />
    <bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>`

and with @Transational and @Autowired as you do, it is ok

If you don't configure transaction, you can use openSession() only, and add closeSession when you want to finish session